# Sonarqube background analysis fails, reports smells plugin does not exist

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have a brand new sonarqube installation (6.7.1.35068) which is being invoked from a brand-new jenkins server (2.102) using the maven goal.  Both are running as services on ec2-linux which is fully patched.

At first it worked.

Then, it sonar began reporting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin [smells] does not exist
```

and refusing to run the background analysis, although the jenkins build reports success.

I can run the jenkins job twice in a row and get a success and a failure without changing anything in the servers or the code.  And then three failures in a row, then four successes in a row.

The plugin does indeed exist, and the sonar server show it is loaded in its configuration reporting.

I have looked at file permissions on the machine, and everything seems to be owned by the right user with the right permissions.

Has anyone seen this behavior?  Any ideas about what other troubleshooting I could do?

Many thanks for any help.

EDIT:  Here is the content of sonar.log at startup.

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.01.22 13:48:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2018.01.22 13:48:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.01.22 13:48:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonar/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonar/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonar/temp/conf/es
2018.01.22 13:48:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.01.22 13:48:03 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.01.22 13:48:03 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.01.22 13:48:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2018.01.22 13:48:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonar]: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.1.4.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process7588018711976818336properties
2018.01.22 13:48:28 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is up
2018.01.22 13:48:28 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='ce', ipcIndex=3, logFilenamePrefix=ce]] from [/opt/sonar]: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:./lib/ce/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.1.4.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process7608302589622094268properties
2018.01.22 13:48:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up
2018.01.22 13:48:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up
```

And that "no modules loaded" from the plugins service doesn't look so good.  In my defense, I was looking at the sonarqube_system_info.json and it reports:

```
  "Plugins": {
    "groovy": "1.5 [Groovy]",
    "java": "5.0.1.12818 [SonarJava]",
    "smells": "4.0.0 [Code Smells]",
    "web": "2.5.0.476 [Web]",
    "xml": "1.4.3.1027 [SonarXML]",
    "clover": "3.1 [Clover]",
    "scmmercurial": "1.1.1 [Mercurial]",
    "Sonargraph": "3.5 [Sonargraph]",
    "aemrules": "0.9 [AEM Rules for SonarQube]",
    "checkstyle": "3.7 [Checkstyle]",
    "javascript": "4.0.0.5862 [SonarJS]",
    "status": "3.0.1 [SVG Badges]"
  },
```

Comment: Hi, could you please send us the list of installed plugins displayed at server startup in the logs/sonar.log ? Thanks

Comment: And could you please tell us if this is happening for all analysis, or only for some of them ?

Comment: I apologize, I’m not totally sure what “all analysis” means.  The sonar:sonar maven goal always seems to succeed.  The background task sometimes works and sometimes doesn’t. When the background task is successful it takes something like 25 seconds and when it fails it takes about a second. It seems to try to do the smells plug-in first, can’t load it, and then doesn’t continue. I can’t figure out the pattern for when the background task succeeds or fails.

Comment: Thanks, I've been able to reproduce this issue, but only when an analysis has been starting before upgrading the server and removing a plugin : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10315
If you're sure that the plugin is still there, there could another issue if you're using the Datacenter Edition.
Is it your case ?

Comment: I am not using the Datacenter Edition; at least not to my knowledge.  I installed using
`sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/sonar.repo http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sonar-pkg/rpm/sonar.repo`
`sudo yum install sonar`
The stack trace of that JIRA entry matches the stack trace I'm getting.  If I did have an analysis and a plugin installation running the same time (which I don't know I did?), is there a way to clean up the server?

Comment: Any new thoughts on this?  Is there a way to retry a failed background job?  I've just purchased a license, so I can submit a support ticket if that's helpful?

Comment: I recommend you to jump into this thread : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarqube/IPjmDeGDUFc/dHMfJooXAQAJ. Sebastien has explained how to detect a wrong configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is probably coming from a wrong usage of SonarQube, most probably by using multiple server on the same database.
See more details about how to detect this in thread : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarqube/IPjmDeGDUFc/dHMfJooXAQAJ

Comment: I've started a new thread over on the Google group, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/sonarqube/oBEOXrVg2D8).  I'm not sure what the misconfiguration could be.  It's a new server.  With a new database.

Comment: Nope - I'm an idiot.  There was another sonar server.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, I'm glad that you've solved your issue